# Imacros Extract TXT after word

Tags: imacros

I really need help for get the code with this case:

```
<tr class="detail-middle">
 <td colspan="4">
  <span class="font-bold">Address</span>
   <p>
     <strong>Orin Fade</strong>
     <br>
     19 rue marciere
     <br>
     Lyon
     <br>
     Lyon
     <br>
     France
     <br>
     Phone Number: +33 0478372730
   </p>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I use imacros code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:"Address" EXTRACT=TXT
```

but i need th TXT after TXT address, can imacros get after any word?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative positioning in your case:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:"Address"
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=P ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Comment: Thanks alot shugar,  my problem is fixed,, :)